# Queue Manager picked up backup configuration

Tags: ibm-mq

Could you please let me know is it possible for a queue manager to pickup the old configuration. I came to know about this after finding that two of our channels showed the old ciphers which I had changed them recently.

Comment: I don't think it is possible for the QM to just pick up any configuration. Maybe someone or some automated tool you use rerun an old config script?

Comment: @Attila Repasi: Thanks for the response.Ok, lets suppose some automated script or someone rerun the old config, but I do not the alteration dates for the channels which I have changed them 2 months ago. I see old date of 2016 which is strange for me. Could you please comment here

Comment: Its not possible for MQ to revert to old definitions, for example when you do display channel, MQ will look in the config files for the details and return them - there's no caching of old stuff. 

However, where did you see the new/old values - for example runmqsc display channel status contains the details from when the channel started, whereas runmqsc display channel shows the values for the next time the channel starts

Actually scratch that - if you have old alteration dates then it feels like you either didnt make the changes or something has restored from a backup

Comment: @JasonE Exactly, as you mentioned something has restored from a backup. Could you please explain more here, like how it could have happened.

Comment: Its something not MQ related, more likely at the o/s or third party level level... MQ has nothing which could do that - once a definition is changed, its changed - there's no history kept which could be restored.